# Create group with Telegram's API

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to create a group and assign users to it with Telegrams API? Could not find any method like this in it's method list: https://core.telegram.org/methods

I am using php as my server language.

Comment: The createChat() func has a param Users, which can be used to create a chat with multiple users. Have you tried this? https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.createChat

Comment: nope, but I not sure if chat == group. Moreover I am don't understand what kind of API it is.

Comment: Any method that takes an [`InputPeer`](https://core.telegram.org/type/InputPeer) accepts a `chat_id` as a member, and that chat_id is your "group". I think there's some term inconsistency that's crept in as telegram has evolved.

Answer (score 2):

Received answer from Telegram: "currently creating groups is impossible via Telegram's API"

Comment: has there been any addition for creating group chat by JAVA API ?

Answer (score 1):

Telegram's API Methods had this create Channel method where you can create SuperGroups/Channels:

[Link](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.createChannel)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use [this](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.createChannel) endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it is working for me. You can create a chat with:

String name;

TLVector < TLAbsInputUser > contacts;

contacts.add(new TLInputUserContact(uid));

TLAbsStatedMessage result=api.doRpcCall(new TLRequestMessagesCreateChat(contacts, name));

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer.What is the api variable here.I am also trying to implement it in java.
I am trying the function - 
client.messagesCreateChat(users, "Test");
users is a vector of type : TLVector<TLAbsInputUser>